# Building a DSL query language

Tags: python, django, dsl

i'm working on a project (written in Django) which has only a few entities, but many rows for each entity.

In my application i have several static "reports", directly written in plain SQL. The users can also search the database via a generic filter form. Since the target audience is really tech-savvy and at some point the filter doesn't fit their needs, i think about creating a query language for my database like [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) or [Jira's advanced search](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching).

I found http://sourceforge.net/projects/littletable/ and http://www.quicksort.co.uk/DeeDoc.html, but it seems that they only operate on in-memory objects. Since the database can be too large for holding it in-memory, i would prefer that the query is translated in SQL (or better a Django query) before doing the actual work.

Are there any library or best practices on how to do this?

Comment: You could look this Zope add-on as exmaple: http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/AdvancedQuery.html

Comment: But SQL is already DSL )

Answer (score 14):

Writing such a DSL is actually surprisingly easy with [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), and what ho—there's already an example available for doing just what you want, in Django. You see, Django has this fancy thing called a [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) which make the Django querying side of things fairly easy.

At DjangoCon EU 2012, Matthieu Amiguet gave a session entitled *Implementing Domain-specific Languages in Django Applications* in which he went through the process, right down to implementing such a DSL as you desire. [His slides, which include all you need, are available on his website.](http://www.matthieuamiguet.ch/media/misc/djangocon2012/djangocon2012.html) The final code (linked to from the last slide, anyway) is available at http://www.matthieuamiguet.ch/media/misc/djangocon2012/resources/compiler.html.

Reinout van Rees also produced some [good comments on that session](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2012/06/04/domain-specific-languages.html). (He normally does!) These cover a little of the missing context.

You see in there something very similar to YQL and JQL in the examples given:

- `groups__name="XXX" AND NOT groups__name="YYY"`
- `(modified > 1/4/2011 OR NOT state__name="OK") AND groups__name="XXX"`

It can also be tweaked very easily; for example, you might want to use `groups.name` rather than `groups__name` (I would). This modification could be made fairly trivially (allow `.` in the FIELD token, by modifying `t_FIELD`, and then replacing `.` with `__` before constructing the `Q` object in `p_expression_ID`).

So, that satisfies simple querying; it also gives you a good starting point should you wish to make a more complex DSL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately further development on this project has been put on hold so I cannot give this a try at the moment. However, from a quick look this looks like a good solution. If the development continues, I will definitely try this and will happily accept your answer.

Comment: I opened bounty on this question, because I need exactly the same thing. This answer seems to be brilliant to me, precisely what I have been looking for. The slides are very helpful. I will dive into this problem next week and hopefully I'll be soon able to validate this approach and award you.

Comment: This is exactly what I'd like as well. This, leading to search results or reports, would make Django models even more powerful. Guess we've all been spoiled by Jira :)

Answer (score 3):

I've faced exactly this problem - a large database which needs searching.  I made some static reports and several fancy filters using [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (very easy with django) just like you have.

However the power users were clamouring for more.  I decided that there already was a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) that they all knew - [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).  The question was how to make it secure enough.

So I used django permissions to give the power users permission to make SQL queries in a new table.  I then made a view for the not-quite-so-power users to use these queries.  I made them take optional parameters.  The queries were run using Python's lower level [DB-API](http://www.amk.ca/python/writing/DB-API.html) which django is using under the hood for its ORM anyway.

The real trick was opening a read only database connection to run these queries just to make sure that no updates were ever run.  I made a read only connection by creating a different user in the database with lower permissions and opening a specific connection for that in the view.

TL;DR - SQL is the way to go!

Comment: I already thought of adding the possibility for raw SQL queries, but i'm not very happy with this. Doing SQL queries in a fast and smart manner is sometimes really tricky. So i (and you) might end up executing queries which put a lot of load to the database. And you have to make sure that the sql interface does not let you select data from other tables or you end up with an information disclosure vulnerability (-> more complex to administer). However, even tech-savvy may not know (or dont want to know) SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the form of your data, the types of queries your users need to use, and the frequency that your data is updated, an alternative to the pure SQL solution suggested by Nick Craig-Wood is to index your data in [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and then run queries against it.

Solr is an added layer of complexity (configuration, data synchronization) but it is super-fast, can handle large datasets, and provides a (relatively) intuitive query language.

Comment: I think a full-blown search framework is big overkill (because of the mentioned complexity). The data is updated regulary, so it would require a lot of code/logic to keep the to datastores in sync.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own SQL-ish language using [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing), actually. There is even pretty verbose [example](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/simpleSQL.py) you could extend.